# async.eachSeries in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a loop in `node.js`

```
for (var i in files){
    var all = fs.readdirsync("./0");
    async.eachSeries(all, function(item){
        check(item); 
   }
}
```

The `check(item)` has a callback to another function.

As I can see, the `async.eachSeries` doesn't execute synchronously. The loop continues to execute the other items, before the callback in the `check()` function is finish.

How do I make the loop wait until the iteration is finished (including the callback)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `check` accepts a callback, we can use [`mapSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapseriesarr-iterator-callback) to achieve that.

```
async.mapSeries(files, function(file, outerCB) {
  var all = fs.readdirsync("./0");
  async.mapSeries(all, function(item, cb){
      check(item, cb);
  }, outerCB);
}, function(err, results) {
  // This is called when everything's done
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Outer loop needs to be async also.  One of the the methods is to use 2 eachSeries loops or outer loop can be in parallel (each) if the files don't have to be processed in series:

```
var async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(files, function(file, outCb) 
{
  var all = fs.readFileSync(file);

  async.eachSeries(all, function(item, inCb) 
  {
    check(item);
    inCb(null);  // inner callback
  }, 
  function(err) 
  {
    outCb(null);  // outer callback
  });
},
function(err) 
{
  console.log('all done!!!');
});
```